# How do I check if the time on android device is set by network or by user?

Tags: android

I need to have a function that returns a boolean if a time on a device is set by user or it is a default network time. Searching the internet gave me no results. Please, share some knowledge on me

Comment: you can check if automatic time and date is enabled or not if enabled so it definitely set by system and if disabled then set by user

Comment: @UsamaAltaf how? that is the point of my question - how do I check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way and to find out more go to [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global#AUTO_TIME)

```
try {
        if(Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME) == 1)
        {
            // Auto Enabled
        }
        else
        {
            // Disabed
        }
    } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean isTimeAutomatic(Context c) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(c.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1;
    } else {
        return android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(c.getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1;
    }
}
```